# Magento 2.4 Catalogue Search Not Working with 2 and 3 word

Tags: magento, magento2

We are facing issue with Catalogue search with 2 and 3 Word. you can Search with GC word in website But result Not showing all

https://www.dentalstall.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=gc

I also Set keyword length 2 in admin area.

Kindly Help

Awaiting for your response.

Comment: Found any solution bro ?

Comment: I have another issue can you help me?

Comment: I will try, please tell me what issue ?

Comment: I want filter product based on attributes.  But collection does't work.

Comment: $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('display_listing', 1)->load(); 

This code is not working in list.phtml